# ssh rsa or dsa connection fail

Tags: ssh, rsa

I explain steps for make rsa key.

create rsa key

```
[user@host01 .ssh]$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
64:ae:ab:be:df:39:93:48:0d:7f:f1:8c:3e:7a:92:ae user@host01
```

It copy to host02

```
[user@host01 .ssh]$ ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub user@host02
10
user@host02's password:
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'user@host02'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

change permission of host02's authorized_keys file

```
 # chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

(or # chmod 644 authorized_keys, tests both 600, 644)

It's the output of id_rsa

> -rw------- 1 user group 1675 Apr 17 17:27 /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

attempt ssh connection (host01 -vvv log)

```
[user@ans1 .ssh]$ ssh host02 -vvv -i id_rsa
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to host02 [host02] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file id_rsa type 1
debug1: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 114/256
debug2: bits set: 502/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 26
debug1: Host '192.168.0.12' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug2: bits set: 522/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: id_rsa (0x2b140ca82bf0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 192.168.0.12.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@host02's password:
```

Comment: Your key is corrupted. Regenerate them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines

```
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
```

are cause for concern.  Could you start again, **showing** us each step as you create the public key, copy it over (`ssh-copy-id` is a good way of doing that, well done), and then try to use it?

Comment: Do you want re try all steps?

Comment: Now, in dsa before make a rsa file, then I'm add rsa key. I delete dsa logs that I wrote question before.

Comment: I try doing, but be canceled serverfault. T.T
It's too long, not add coments. How can I do?

Comment: **Edit it into your question.**  And yes, I'd like you to re-try all steps, from the start (jkey generation), showing us each step as you do it - both the command and the output.  Cutting and pasting the terminal session is the best way of doing this.

Comment: Yes,i'll had to it. But it' error to long output T.T

Comment: Ah! I understand. Do I edit my question!!!! I'll edit my question tommorow. I get out my office T.T

Comment: I write the ouput!

Comment: Could you add to your question the output of `ls -la /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa` on host01?

Comment: T.T I don't understand your comment. Then I edit the output. I had a stupid. T.T

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad; I can't read that language.  Could you do `export LANG=en_GB` and try that `ls` again?

Comment: I've edit the output. I'm really thanks for your help. T.T

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea why this key isn't validating properly.

Comment: Ok, whatever thanks for your help. T-T

Comment: Good Man! I've got sucess the problem. The problem is SElinux. T.T I've got off SElinux and restart to linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the public key to the external host.

Key-based authentication involves a pair of keys:

- The private key (~/.ssh/id_rsa) *— keep this private!*
- The public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) — copy and paste the contents into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the destination server.

Full instructions are here: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I had to keep id_rsa file in host01 and into authorized_keys of host02 using ssh-copy-id or sftp.
Then I tried connect host01 to host02.
T.T